# How to work with Django ajax "GET method"

Tags: django, ajax, getmethod

I want to do an ajax GET and POST method in Django. My post method is working well, but the GET method isn't. See my codes below.

**Urls**

```
path("getupdates/",views.getupdates,name="getupdates")
```

**views**

```
def getupdates(request):
 if request.user.is_authenticated:
  if request.method == "GET":
   user_instance = User.objects.filter(username=request.user.username)[0]
   info = userinfo.objects.filter(username=user_instance.username)
   game = spinwheel.objects.filter(user=info[0])
   get_value= request.body
   data = {"info":info}
   print(data)
   return render(request,'spin.html',{"info":info})
```

**Js-ajax**

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'getupdates/',
 // datatype: 'json',
 data : data,
 type: 'GET',
 sucess: function(data) {
  console.log("refreshed!")
 }
});
```

I wish to have the ajax GET method update some parts of my HTML.

Comment: _What_ is not working as expected? If you want to update parts of the template then you need to do that in your success function for the ajax request using the response returned by the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can check request.is_ajax().
If this true the case you are returning JsonResponce with your data.
And insert them into your html without reloading the entire page.

*Example*

```
class ViewName(View):
    def get(self, requst):
        if requst.is_ajax():
            # your code

            return JsonResponse({'data': data})

    def post(self, requst):
        # your code
```